# Use POST /sign_in to sign in. GET is not supported. Omniauth-facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

I've [ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth) for frontend and [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) on the backend . Now i've to implement `omniauth-facebook` & `omniauth-goole` logins in my website .Yet i've done facebook login with the following functions

in **config.js (ng-token-auth)**

```
$scope.handleBtnClick = function() {
  console.log('here its')
  $auth.authenticate('facebook')
    .then(function(resp) {
      // handle success
    })
    .catch(function(resp) {
      // handle errors
    });
};
```

At this point , login occurs successfully , but when it redirects it shows me following error in my browser page

> {"errors":["Use POST /sign_in to sign in. GET is not supported."]}

**routes.rb**

```
mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth',:controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => 'omniauth' }
```

**devise.rb**

```
 config.omniauth :facebook,  'APP_KEY', 'APP_SECRET',{ :scope => 'email' }
```

**omniauth controller**

```
class OmniauthController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
        def facebook
            byebug
            @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
            sign_in_and_redirect @user
        end
    end
```

ANd here are my server logs

> Started GET
>   "/omniauth/facebook?auth_origin_url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F%23%2F&omniauth_window_type=sameWindow&resource_class=User"
>   for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-12 18:34:33 +0500 I,
>   [2016-03-12T18:34:33.203521 #5978]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook)
>   Request phase initiated.
>
> Started GET "/omniauth/facebook/callback?code=AQARGivLmOz......" for
>   127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-12 18:34:34 +0500 I, [2016-03-12T18:34:34.189285 #5978]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback phase initiated. I, [2016-03-12T18:34:36.790185 #5978]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook)
>   Callback phase initiated. E, [2016-03-12T18:34:36.790636 #5978] ERROR
>   -- omniauth: (facebook) Authentication failure! csrf_detected: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, csrf_detected | CSRF
>   detected Processing by Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as
>   HTML   Parameters: {"code"=>"AQARGivLmOzsdLxe ..... "} Redirected to
>   http://localhost:3000/auth/sign_in Completed 302 Found in 10ms
>   (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>
> Started GET "/auth/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-12 18:34:36 +0500
>   Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController#new as HTML
>   Completed 405 Method Not Allowed in 1ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord:
>   0.0ms)

Comment: What is byebug doing there in your code , won't that stop the process resulting in timeout ? Also , do you have a callback url defined in your facebook application ?

Comment: Take a look here , move your changes to secrets.yml - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672015/google-oauth2-with-devise-and-omniauth-processed-as-failure

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth',:controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => 'omniauth' }, via: [:get, :post]
```

Comment: I verified that I got the same error without the above code in my `routes.rb` file. Maybe OP didn't understand this was for that file.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I've found a possible solution. After some research, that appears to be a facebook error. 
After debugging the app and devise, I figured out that I'm having this error: "error":{"message":"This IP can't make requests for that application.","type":"OAuthException" 
For that reason, devise is redirecting to error handling 
To solve this, I have to add my public ip on facebook (advance settings, allowed ips) in order to solve the problem. 
Hope this help